# 401 Unauthorized response cached and unable to clear it

Tags: c#, .net, iis, web

Any HttpWebRequest I make to my local IIS Express host (localhost:55717) with cache control set to RequestCacheLevel.Default return a 401 without contacting IIS - the server process isn't even running.

The response is coming from cache, the the IsFromCache property admits this fact, but I've cleared the cache time and again!

Here's the response:

```
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcVHJ1bmtcU0cuQXNnYXJkLkRldmljZUVzdGF0ZS5SZXN0QXBpSG9zdFxTRy5Bc2dhcmQuRGV2aWNlRXN0YXRlLlJlc3RBcGlIb3N0?=
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate,NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 31 Jul 2012 18:00:22 GMT
Content-Length: 6154
Age: 240
```

The date is, at the time of writing, over and hour old. To be clear, any request to localhost:55717/blahblah-nonexistent produces the same 401.

Anyone know of this problem?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the application(pool) on the server?

Comment: @PhonicUK Hi - I'm using IIS Express and the process isn't even running! So the response can only be coming from client cache.